# Using a variable inside getElementByID to set focus()

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be dead simple. I'm trying to use a variable in getElementByID, which expects a quoted literal value. There are multiple fields that I want to run the same validation code on and, if there's an error, return to the field with the problem. Looking at other questions and answers, it seems that what I'm trying to do won't work, so there must be a better option, but I don't know what it is.

Here's what I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>I just want to focus!</title>
<script>
// this section of code would validate 3 similar fields
function FocusFoo(FocusMe) {  
    // validation routine here
    // on failure, I want to select the field that called the function       
    document.getElementById(FocusMe.value).focus();
    // fails because getElementById expects a quoted literal.
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="FooForm" name="FooForm" action="foo.php" method="post">
<p>Leave Foo 1 to test focus.</p>
<p>Foo 1: <input type="text" id="Foo1" name="Foo1" onBlur="FocusFoo(this)"></p>
<p>Foo 2: <input type="text" id="Foo2" name="Foo2" onBlur="FocusFoo(this)"></p>
<p>Foo 3: <input type="text" id="Foo3" name="Foo3" onBlur="FocusFoo(this)"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There isn't really a need to *get* the element; you already have it in `FocusMe` – `FocusMe.focus();`. Also, `getElementById()` doesn't expect a literal, specifically. It expects a string value, which can be created with a literal.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to:

```
document.getElementById(FocusMe.id).focus();
```

since you need to pass the ID not the value to the getElementById function

OR just (easier as noted by the comments)

```
FocusMe.focus();
```

Comment: Wouldn't FocusMe.focus() be easier?

Comment: Yep!  Not going to argue with that.

Comment: I changed the function as described -- using FocusMe.focus() -- but when I tab out of any field, the next field receives focus after the procedure runs.